# how to navigate back directly from my last view to first view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have added a navigation controller in iphone app from my home screen it takes to a tableview from the table view it takes to the detail.I am able to navigate between the views back and forth.what I want is navigate directly from detail view to my home screen.Is there any possibility to do that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save)]; self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = saveButton;   



id1 =    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id1"];
theTitle = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"theTitle"];
self.title=theTitle;
NSLog(@"hi %@", id1);
hello=@"hello";
NSLog(@"ahhhha sdfgs :%@",theTitle);

urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPark?parkid=%@",self.id1];
baseURL =[[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]retain];

jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];

NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

boom=[items objectForKey:@"description"];
latitude=[items objectForKey:@"latitude"];
longitude=[items objectForKey:@"longitude"];
NSLog(@"retard:%@",latitude);
  NSLog(@"retard:%@",longitude);
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", boom];  
[self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]; 


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:latitude forKey:@"lat"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: longitude forKey:@"lot"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: theTitle forKey:@"title"];
```

}

Comment: It would help us help you if you could post some code your using.

Comment: Your code had nothing to do with the question, I have rolled back the edit. You can change it back if you disagree, but the answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to just set custom back button and set button click event
// hide back button first

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;  

/// Add new Back Button 

UIButton *back = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
back.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 32);
[back setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
[back setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[back addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn;

/// Press button event to go to root or say home page
-(void)backBtnTap:(id)sender{
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: cocoa:dude its a continuation of the previous question dat you answered me i want add a bar button item in navigation controller..cud u help  me out

Comment: check my updated answer with created a bar button. you have to add image of back button style

Comment: you are using navigation controller ?

Comment: add image of backBtn.png in your project

Comment: add this line before you add your new button self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;

Comment: try this:UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:bttnImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Back:)];
[self.navigationController setHidesBackButton:YES];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: customItem];

Comment: @cocoa:this is de thing i used in ViewDidLoad. still not able to add the button

Comment: dude..if u want ill give u my source code...cud u give a check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7605/discussion-between-kingston-and-cocoa-matters)

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

this will pop back to the rootviewController of navigation controller